# How do I connect two nodes in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, centos7

Now I have two nodes(192.168.72.129, 192.168.72.130)
It's the setting in config/elasticsearch.yml
======node-1======

```
cluster.name: cluster-es
node.name: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.port: 9200
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
transport.port: 9300
http.max_content_length: 200mb
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.72.129","192.168.72.130"]
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2
network.tcp.keep_alive: true
network.tcp.no_delay: true
transport.tcp.compress: true
cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance: 16
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries: 16
cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries: 16
```

======node-2======

```
cluster.name: cluster-es
node.name: node-2
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.port: 9200
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
transport.port: 9300
http.max_content_length: 200mb
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.72.129","192.168.72.130"]
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2
network.tcp.keep_alive: true
network.tcp.no_delay: true
transport.tcp.compress: true
cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance: 16
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries: 16
cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries: 16
```

but when I `curl http://192.168.72.129:9200/_cat/nodes`
there is only one node to show, how can I solve it?

Comment: can you provide the logs when you start node-2

Comment: The log just show
[2022-12-13T18:20:31,798][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [node-2] master node changed {previous [], current [{node-2}{q_n5hicAS2mYOF2fV6ay5Q}{eHBdx9tvQPiIo4ARossNqw}{192.168.72.130}{192.168.72.130:9300}{dim}{ml.machine_memory=1019572224, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, term: 14, version: 38, reason: Publication{term=14, version=38}
[2022-12-13T18:20:32,084][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [node-2] publish_address {192.168.72.130:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2022-12-13T18:20:32,084][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-2] started

Comment: are these two nodes connected on the n/w

Comment: I guess they are all be in the same domain because I built them with vmware in my computer.